# Google BigQuery-TimeZone Conversion

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a requirement to convert UTC datetime field to est in bigquery using Standard SQL

I tried below Query:

```
SELECT
  CallRailCallId,

  DATETIME(StartTime ,
    "America/Los_Angeles") AS adjustedTime
FROM
  `Tablel`
```

But I got this error as below :

> No matching signature for function DATETIME for argument types: DATETIME, STRING. Supported signatures: DATETIME(INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64); DATETIME(DATE, TIME); DATETIME(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATETIME(DATE)

Can anyone help in this, what wrong with my query?

Answer (score 5):

You can convert it to a timestamp first, then interpret it in a particular time zone.

```
SELECT
  CallRailCallId,
  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(StartTime),
    "America/Los_Angeles") AS adjustedTime
FROM
`Tablel`
```